# Switching cameras for video on the fly on android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I know it is possible as the camera app that comes with my droid phone does it, but for the life of me, I don't seem to be able to switch cameras on the fly either for video or a standard camera (which leads me to suspect I'm not doing it right!)

Currently, I have an event for the button

```
btnSwitchCamera.Click += new EventHandler(btnSwitchCamera_Click);
```

prior to that, I check for the number of cameras - if there is only one camera, the event is not enabled.

The switch code looks like this

```
private void btnSwitchCamera_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isBackCamera == false)
        {
            try
            {
                RunOnUiThread(delegate
                {
                    camera.Release();
                    camera = Android.Hardware.Camera.Open(1);
                });
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.RuntimeException)
            {
                alertMsg(context, Application.Context.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.videoErrorTitle),
                    Application.Context.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.videoFailToConnect));
                return;
            }
            isBackCamera = true;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                RunOnUiThread(delegate
                {
                    camera.Release();
                    camera = Android.Hardware.Camera.Open(0);
                });
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.RuntimeException)
            {
                alertMsg(context, Application.Context.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.videoErrorTitle),
                    Application.Context.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.videoFailToConnect));
                return;
            }
            isBackCamera = false;
        }
    }
```

If I click the button, the app dies claiming that I cannot connect to the service.

The video record code is nothing special - it's a bog standard set the surface, do the holder, and start/stop recording.

Am I doing this right? From the docs, I need to release the camera then open the camera with the appropriate camera number (Android.Hardware.Camera.NumberOfCameras - 1)

The manifest is correctly set.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: How many cameras does your device have?

Comment: The docs suggests you release on another thread as the Release method might take some time to finish up.